# How would I mount docker container filesystem?

Tags: git, docker

How would I mount docker container images so that I could modify them with external tools ?

This means: from the docker hosts, mounting the image without launching a container on it, as a normal filesystem. I should'nt need to run a container for this.

I'd like to update the image directly this way, then probably send something like `docker commit`. With `lxc` tools (in ubuntu for example) its quite easy as it is directly available to host in `/var/lib/lxc/MYCONTAINER/rootfs`.

I know about workarounds, but:

- I don't feel that using `Dockerfile` context (and `ADD`) is rather convenient nor adapted: I don't have a specific directory to send, but rather would use a combination of tools to change only specific files (think of `rsync` for instance).
- Even if `ADD` contains some sort of algorithm that only adds new files to the image appropriately, I still have to send all files as *docker context* for the build command !.
- I could update the container image by calling tools pre-installed in the image. But `apt-get install git` on a `debian` image doubles the size of the image. And git won't be used in production. And removing tools after usage is not always so easy, besides that it feels wrong.
- I could use `-v` docker build's option to mount a directory full of tools... and their dependencies. This feels hard if you need more than a very simple bash-script.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, I would run a container (I know you're against this) and then, e.g., rsync files to /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/CONTAINERID/rootfs, then docker commit.

Comment: Even if a container is run, you don't really use it, nor it's image is not garbled with non-production tools. So your solution is interesting. But this pre-suppose also that you are using ``devicemapper`` driver, I'm not sure it's so easy with ``aufs`` for example.

Comment: That's true. Unfortunately I have no experience with aufs. Good luck!